# Error in setup:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature is not available in JAXB RI 2.0

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

Application working fine with Jaxb1.0 and jdk1.6. now need to migrate to jdk1.8 with Jaxb2.0. but am getting error saying Error in setup:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This feature is not available in JAXB RI 2.0

inside my program Validator is deprecated.how to implement schema validation  using jaxb2.0?

Comment: Please show your code and complete error stack trace/messages.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386486/validate-xml-file-against-xml-schema